# Inserting text before the second occurrence of a word in file

Tags: bash, fedora

I'm running Fedora 30 and want to write a bash script. I have a file with test data

```
asdf
asdf
[test]
asdasd
[test]


asdasd
```

i want to insert "lineToInsert" before the second occurrence of [test]

So far i have

```
myVar="lineToInsert"

sed  '/\[test\]/i'$myVar inputTest > test.txt
```

The problem is that this insert "lineToInsert" before every occourrence of [test]. Resulting in

```
asdf
asdf
lineToInsert
[test]
asdasd
lineToInsert
[test]


asdasd
```

What i want is this

```
asdf
asdf
[test]
asdasd
lineToInsert
[test]


asdasd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following if you are ok with `awk`

```
awk -v var="$myVar" '/\[test\]/ && ++count==2{print var ORS $0;next} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk -v var="$myVar" '         ##Starting awk program here, defining var variable of awk which has value of myVar which is a shell variable.
/\[test\]/ && ++count==2{     ##Checking condition if a line has test in it and count is 2 then do following.
  print var ORS $0            ##Printing variable var then ORS and current line value here.
  next                        ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                             ##Closing BLOCK for condition here.
1                             ##1 will print edited/non-edited current line.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
myVar="lineToInsert"
sed -e '/\[test\]/i '"${myVar}" inputTest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using sed.
your input is in firstfile.txt
result is in secondfile.txt

```
sed 's/\[test\]/\[test\]\nYOURSTRING\n/g' firstfile.txt > secondfile.txt
```